# How to delete corresponding mipmap icon images all at once?

Tags: android-studio, mipmaps

Because Android studio adds padding to custom icons(this is a known problem) i was playing with different images and putting them using File->new ImageAsset.

Now i have too many of same image.png in all folders.

Is there way to delete all corresponding images at once in all mipmap folders?[image: dddd]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Android Studio change your folder view from whatever it is (project/packages etc) to Android and it will group the similar images together in one file. All you have to do is delete the file

Comment: i will accept your answer, even if you responded much later than me. just because i want to give points to other people rather than myself!

Answer (score 6):

Nevermind, when you delete image from mipmap folder, android studio asks to delete all other corresponding images at once! solved